# On edit move row under the appropriate header Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a database, I'm hoping to try and create a script that will move the person's row based on their rank to a header within the same database page. However, even after all my research I have failed to find a script that can help me achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by rank? And what do you have in mind in general? I'm kind of confused what exactly you need

Comment: So its a database of people within a program and i'd like it so when their ranking within the program changes it moves the row under the respective header, hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried to find a script that can do it but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: @THess If you need any more information, let me know.

Comment: @nysm Could you please provide an example Sheet that you are using, and describe a possible scenario? That would help us provide you a tailored answer. Cheers

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MYLYvUWeCHUkuy8A_WOoeuSwuyNoQr4E9jOsBVfj3_A/edit#gid=0

Heres an example.

Comment: @carlesgg97 hope that explains more!

Comment: The multiple "row headings" are causing your problem. Solution - get rid of them. Insert a New Column B and type an appropriate header in Cell B3. Insert "Status values as "1.Admin", "2. Moderator", "3.Support", "4.Member" - this will ensure that the data sorts consistently. Now when you change a persons Rank, also change their status; then resort the data by Column B. I left an example in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Tedinoz's answer seems to do the trick. Can you confirm this is what you were looking for @nysm? Cheers

Comment: I was hoping to do it in script with the headers, would this be possible? @carlesgg97